# Is it good practice to write a getter for a handle?

Tags: getter, handle, glfw

I am using glfw to create a window.
Right now I'm having trouble getting input from the keyboard, beacause the function expects a handle to the window, which is private and not in the same class.

I was thinking about writing a getter for the handle like this:

```
public long getWindowHandle() {
        return windowHandle;
}
```

But is it good practice to to that?

Answer (score 0):

Use of get and set to access member variables directly is an anti-pattern. It means the class was badly designed. However sometimes you have to do it. But if a windowHandle is private, it's private for a reason, and you are simply subverting that.